# TCP IP Client in WPF for Ubuntu 14 Server

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, video-streaming, tcpclient

I am trying to create TCP IP Client in WPF GUI / C#.NET for a Ubunu Server.

Problem: I am able to connect to the server machine , the connection work correctly, send the message correctly and the ubuntu console show as well , Client Connected and sent this command like Start Video Feed on the server but When it comes to Read the Response nothing happens - It does not read the byte array that should be returned by the Ubuntu Server. Actually on message - 102 it should start the video feed on the server and return back the video feed byte array which should be read further and display the video. No code written yet to display the video feed as I am unable to read the feed from the server however, the client sends the commands(messages) to the server correctly as mentioned can view it on a console of the Ubuntu server machine.  Please suggest thanks !!

Below is the code please have a look and suggest me what I am doing wrong :

```
namespace POC_TCP_Listener
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private int WhichEventFired = 0;

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // string message = "{Site: 1}";
                WhichEventFired = 1; //Start Video Feed
                Thread ClientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConnectToServerAndRetrieveBytes));
                ClientThread.Start();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string st = ex.Message;

            }
        }

        private void ConnectToServerAndRetrieveBytes()
        {

            TcpClient TCP = new TcpClient();
            TCP.Connect("IPAddress", 5001);

            byte[] packet;

            var size = 9;
            var header = 102;
            var siteId = 1;
            var state = 1;

            if (WhichEventFired == 1)
            {
                header = 102;   // Start Video Feed
            }
            else if (WhichEventFired == 2)
            {
                header = 114; // Stop Video Feed
            }
            else
            {
                header = 115; // query Temperature
            }

            // <8> <115> <1>
            packet = BitConverter.GetBytes(size).Reverse().Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(header).Reverse()).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(siteId).Reverse()).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(state).Reverse()).ToArray();


            // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
            Byte[] data = packet;

            // Get a client stream for reading and writing. 

            NetworkStream stream = TCP.GetStream();

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 

            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
// In the below line - it stops and nothing happens after it - Please Suggest
                while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                // return ms.ToArray();
            }

            stream.Close();
            TCP.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**strong text**
Please suggest why it stops working or let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: WPF is a GUI framework built on .net, the programming language is C#. WPF have nothing to do with the networking parts from .net or the language.

Comment: yes ofcourse ... can you tell me where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that if there are no more packages left, it escapes the while-loop. If you want to check it endlessly you should try using a for. But i am not sure.

Yeah that should be it. If there are no Packages in the moment the while-loop is starting, it terminates itself because there is nothing to read. So you could check if the Ubuntu Server returns you something.